# Pipe operator with the if expression

Tags: f#

Is it possible use the pipe operator with if?

The code I have tried:

```
true
|> (if)
   then "Yes!"
   else "No"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this, as `if...then` is an expression by itself. Why do you want to do this, i.e. what is the objective?

If you want to pipe into some conditional logic you can do it with a `match` statement:

```
match true with
    | true -> "Yes"
    | _  -> "false"
```

this can be written with a `function`, and it will take the first (curried) argument and match on it:

```
let myif =
    function 
        | true -> "Yes"
        | _ -> "false"

true |> myif
```

Otherwise you can re-define `if`, I imagine a lot of people will hate you for that. :-)

```
let myif2 x = if x then "Yes" else "No"

true |> myif2
```

Comment: Running with true |> function
| true -> "Yes!"
| false -> "No"